# How to clear data in Preference Store when uninstalling an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, store, preferences, uninstallation

I'm developing an Eclipse-Plugin which has it's own preference page.
I'm storing some data using IPersistentPreferenceStore, but would like to remove / clear this data upon uninstall of my plugin. Otherwise, whenever I re-install the plugin, I get the old data loaded again from previous installations.

So far I was not successful in finding any hooks / events for eclipse plugin uninstall to notify my plugin.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

A way is that your plug-in explicitly registers a listener to `IProvisioningEventBus` that is an internal API of P2.

Then your listener would be notified if something are about to be removed, clean your preference store if the to be removed plug-in is what you want.