# Eclipse Plug-in:How to clear old values from Preference Page when plugin has been Uninstalled?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.6

I am using Eclipse Helios 3.6 
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705

I have a preferences page plug-in which sets a path which I need for my application. When I un-install my plug-in, the set path still remains in memory.  I am fetching the value of the path I set from getTextControl().getText(), this returns the previously set value.

I read in [How to clear data in Preference Store when uninstalling an Eclipse plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269505/how-to-clear-data-in-preference-store-when-uninstalling-an-eclipse-plugin) , that you need to use IProvisioningEventBus. I don't have much of an idea how this can be used. I'd be grateful, if anyone could provide a little more elaborate answer or if there is another way to clear the old value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running eclipse from the command line with the -clean flag.

Comment: Thanks Lionel. But, I need a way where I can handle such a thing from my code rather than do it explicitly.